# Как передать дерево для отрисовки на HTML странице

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Модель представляет собой [дерево частых наборов](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNx6s.png) . Как я могу передать дерево в представление ? Возможно лучше передать JSON, а рисовать и рассчитывать координаты узлов и связей с помощью JS. Может можно сгенерировать svg в модели ?

Comment: А что вам, собственно, мешает передать в представление дерево?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, Посчитать координаты узлов в модели и передать объект ? А потом просто в <svg> рисовать его ?